# Is there a way to do multiple inserts in a single query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'd like to do multiple inserts in a simple Query, and I'm using the upsert_all ClassMethod, for example:

```
books = [] 

10.times do |i|
  books << { name: "book #{i}" }
end

Book.upsert_all(books)
```

however, this method do not instantiate any models or call callbacks or validations.
and if I save a record of books without names, the upsert_all would save them for me (and it would not comply with the validations of the model)

Is there a way to do multiple inserts in a single query using the upsert_all or any other way?

PS: I wouldn't want to use any gem like activerecord-import

```
# models/book.rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Basically you want to trigger model validation in bulk insert?

Comment: Imagine you had a uniqueness validation on an attribute and the two records in the bulk had the same value on that attribute. Would you expect the import to pass because the validation is done before the bulk insert is done? Or would you expect the import to fail because each entry is validated individually after all previous records have been written to the db? And would you expect a rollback of the whole import in such a case?